# DOM event fired by window resize

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have a page that has a fairly complicated layout. When the page is initially opened there's a problem with the aligment of some of the elements. However, this problem can be resolved (permanently) by changing the size of the brower window.

Obviously I don't want the user to have to resize the browser window in order for the page to display correctly, so I'm wondering if there's a way I can programatically trigger the handlers attached to the browser's resize event when the page first loads?

### Update

I found out that the following code will fire any handlers attached to the window's resize event:

```
if (document.createEvent) { // W3C
    var ev = document.createEvent('Event');
    ev.initEvent('resize', true, true);
    window.dispatchEvent(ev);
} else { // IE
    document.fireEvent('onresize');
}
```

I verified that this does indeed trigger the window's resize event handlers, but when I run this code in the Firebug console, it doesn't fix the layout problem.

So it seems that the code which fixes the layout when the browser is resized is not a handler of the window's resize event, but a handler of something else. How can I go about tracking down which event handler I need to fire?

Is it possible that when the browser is manually resized, the resize event propogates down to all the children of window, but when the code above is executed, the resize handler only fires on window itself?

Comment: Does the problem fix itself, or do you have resize handlers that fix it for you?

Comment: this seems a bit quirk and hacky. Probably there's a cleaner way to solve the problem. Post a demo page

Comment: can't you deal with the alignment with css in the first place ? that would be the way to go, think about it: would you use a service or/from a website that automaticly resizes you're browser ?

Comment: @Alnitak the problem seems to fix itself. I'm not aware of any resize handlers

Comment: You can see if there are any resize handlers on the page in google chrome by opening `Developer tools` -> `Scripts tab` -> `Event Listener Breakpoints` -> `Control` -> `Resize` and then refreshing the page.

Comment: Why implement a band-aid solution when you can just fix the rendering of the page? I understand this isn't the question.. but it would solve the issue at hand.

Comment: @rlemon I'm using a very old version of ExtJS to create the components on the page any lay them out. It is exceedingly difficult to control precisely how ExtJS places components. I agree that what I'm attempting is not the best solution, but it's better than none at all.

Comment: It is very hard to help with the limited information you have here... Can you at least provide a screenshot of the 'bad' rendering? This to me ***SCREAMS*** CSS fix.

Comment: @rlemon As I said, Ext JS does not really support/encourage using CSS for layout, instead you're supposed to use the layout managers it provides

Comment: @rlemon the specific problem with the layout is very Ext JS specific. My question is simply "how can I programatically trigger the code that executes when the browser is resized"

Comment: The problem is you are using a third party tool which you do not understand / use properly (or it is a poor tool, in which case find a better one, or DIY). But I guess if you want to [Program by Coincidence](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence).... My #1 recommendation would be fix the root problem (first find it).

Comment: To execute the code you need to first figure out what code is being run..

Answer (score 11):

For IE compatibility

```
function fireResize(){
    if (document.createEvent) { // W3C
        var ev = document.createEvent('Event');
        ev.initEvent('resize', true, true);
        window.dispatchEvent(ev);
    }
    else { // IE
        element=document.documentElement;
        var event=document.createEventObject();
        element.fireEvent("onresize",event);
    }
};
fireResize();
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried this in Chrome, Firefox and IE11, and it works:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0);
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should investigate why the page does not render correctly in the first place. Relying on a re-render after resize sounds hackish to me.

Although manually firing a `resize` event might not give the correct results, you can also try to hide/show an event triggering a re-render event. This might result in screen flickering, so it is not the optimal solution.

Comment: +1 "I think you should investigate why the page does not render correctly in the first place."

Answer (score 0):

Can also be done with [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent):

```
var ev = new CustomEvent('resize'); //instantiate the resize event
ev.initEvent('resize');

window.dispatchEvent(ev); // fire 'resize' event!
```

Answer (score -1):

There's an window.onresize event that fires when the window is resized. You can force a resize by changing the window.width or height by a pixel and then setting it back on a small timer.

With jQuery you can do something like this:

```
$(function() { 
   $(window).width($(window).width() + 1);
  // delay so DOM can update and not batch UI updates
  setTimeout(function() { $(window).width($(window).width() -1); },3);
});
```

FWIW, I've seen this myself before, but I agree with @bouke that you should defintitely try to identify what's causing the broken layout. I find it usually has to do with floated content or overflow of text containers that causes these sorts of problems.

Comment: The code doesn't do anything, it doesn't even fire the artifical handler that can be fired with `$(window).trigger("resize");` if you have a bound a jQuery event.

Comment: I tried running `$(window).width($(window).width() + 50);` in the Firebug console, but it has no impact on the window size. It seems unlikely to me that a browser would allow itself to be resized from JS code as this would be open to abuse